# Goldengate timestamp (FFF)

Tags: timestamp, goldengate

Working with Goldengate 19.1.0.0.211019
replicat inbound to Oracle 19.0.0.0.0
consuming a trail file incoming from Nonstop (ie a non-Oracle database).

Column in question from Nonstop is a string containing value of:
"20210723112304812" in format of:
"yyyymmddhhmmssfff" ie timestamp.

In my replicat, I use following colmap in the appropriate map .. target  command:

```
COLMAP ( usedefaults,
TS_UPDATE = @DATE ( 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FFF', 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFF', TS_UPDATE ) );
```

Howevever, finishing, the data stored in Oracle is:
(defined as TIMESTAMP(3) )

```
23-jul-2021 11:23:04.001
```

and other dates either get a ".001" or ".000" value for the fractional second everytime.

I have also tried:

```
@DATE ( 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FFFFFF', 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFF', TS_UPDATE )
```

with same results.

What format setting should I be using to import/include the fractional second properly from non_oracle DB into Oracle DB with TIMESTAMP(3) ??

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem ..

[PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error)

Solution is:

```
COLMAP ( usedefaults,
TS_UPDATE = @DATE ( 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FFF', 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFF', TS_UPDATE ) );
```

(In all my edits/tests/re-runs, I erroneously edited wrong file .. O.o (but yes, all in initial dev testing, so all good :P ) )